# Javafx Media Player

Tags: java, class, mp3

Why it doesn't work?
I tried change file name, path and still doesn't work.
I get a lot of exeptions.
I don't know what's wrong with this code.
File path /Users/Mariusz/Music/Audio.mp3

I changed my code but still doesn't work.

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Play")) {
        bar.setString(file.getName().split(".mp3")[0]);
        playSound(file); 
}

public void playSound(File file){
    String bip = file.toURI().toString();
    Media hit = new Media(bip);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:150)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media$_MetadataListener.onMetadata(Media.java:499)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.done(MetadataParserImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.ID3MetadataParser.parse(ID3MetadataParser.java:270)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.run(MetadataParserImpl.java:141)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:150)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:450)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:365)
    at MyFrame.playSound(MyFrame.java:300)
    at MyFrame.actionPerformed(MyFrame.java:281)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: what exactly happens? any exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Media constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) takes a URI, not a file path specifier.

The constructor has the following constraints in JavaFX 2.2:

- The supplied URI must conform to RFC-2396 as required by [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).
- Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported.

A space character, as returned by your current `file.getPath()` call, is illegal in a URI.

To be a valid URI, a `' '` must be encoded as `%20`.

To construct a URI for a file, call [file.toURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI%28%29) instead of your current call to `file.getPath()`.