# MediaPlayer in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, media

I am concerned with the fact that JavaFX has suffered some modifications since the day of this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWl98dhvf8Q .

Please, give me some hints for what should I change in this code, or is this kind of code valid, at all? Thank you.

**Here's the code:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;


public class BiPlayer extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group videoPane = new Group();

        Media media = new Media("C:\\Users\\Insanovation\\Downloads\\P.mp4");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

        videoPane.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene (videoPane, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        player.play();
    }
}
```

**Here's the output:**

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1394438858.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\Insanovation\Downloads\F.mp3
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:383)
    at biplayer.BiPLAYER.start(BiPLAYER.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/270894642.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1147985808.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1822121612.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1267032364.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/636718812.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\Insanovation\Downloads\F.mp3
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:381)
    ... 15 more
Exception running application biplayer.BiPLAYER
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Please be very accurate. Are you sure that you installed all dependencies?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_20, yesterday I had it on Ubuntu 14.04, today: Windows 8.1 Pro. I changed the path format for the Windows kind: "C:\\Users\\Insanovation\\Downloads\\F.mp3".

Comment: I edited the question, according to my "Windows situation".

Comment: I don't know whether it is still the case but there was a problem with Java 1.8 and Ubuntu 14 some months ago. The "source" parameter is wrong, it should start with "file:" in your case, please look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016056/458157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the exception that you've copied and pasted, it's clear that the exception thrown is a URISyntaxException. It then lists the problem character, which is at index 2 (the backslash character).

If you look into the documentation of URIs [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), you'll see that only forward slashes are acceptable in URIs. If you changed the backslashes in your path to forward slashes like so:

```
file:C:/Users/Insanovation/Downloads/F.mp4
```

I believe it should work.

Comment: I appreciate your support, though, it's been some time. Up & Accept as answer, for the initiative and maybe that should be the solution!

Comment: I hadn't realized how old this thread was! Wow! I was just browsing the javaFX MediaPlayer related questions. Thanks for the up and accept!